# Adjusting row height correctly

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell, adjustment

Showing dynamic data in table cell make problem for me. I am using

`[titleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(285,9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];`

function for calculating the size now according to size i need to adjust row sizes. but it is inconsistent, Some time it give size(242,18) and (40,18) (showing width,height). when it gives more width for same height the it breaks in two line text and inconsistency begins. if i take less height then it overflow the text and if less in height then some time left a huge white space.

please help me and suggest some proper way for doing this.

Comment: Did you follow any tutorial for setting this up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code seem me correct , there is only one place for modification left in your code that would be use `CGFLOAT_MAX` instead of `9999`.

And Also check the lineBreakMode property, Assign `numberOfLines` With **zero**.

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Comment: @Ishu : Have you sorted out issue ?

Comment: No, actually i am having textviews not labels and CGFLOAT_MAX could not sort problem. this some thing reticules of justifying the in the textViews (justifying the text, ithink i need to replace that with the labels).

Comment: Finally replace all textViews with labels but still get some white spaces in some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is delegate method as follows

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      if (indexPath.row == theRowWhereUwantToIncreaseTheSize) 
      {
           return 105.0f;;
      }
}
```